# DNAT to-destination on interface IP

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

Imagine I have a two IP addresses:

```
eth0:   1.2.3.4
eth0:0  1.2.3.5
gre1    10.0.0.2
```

so I have a traffic from `gre1` and I want to use DNAT to destination `eth0:0` IP address.

But it's not working

I am using:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i gre1 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.5
```

PS: when I down `eth0:0` interface it's DNAT work well which tested with `tcpdump`, but when it's up (it must be up) , it's not working at all (it's hit on iptable but not working)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: First sentence - you show three IP addresses

Comment: Second sentence, "_it's not working_" - how do you know it's not working? What happens when you add the rule? What doesn't happen that you would have expected? If you add a LOG rule immediately before the DNAT does it fire?

Comment: @roaima the source ip address is 10.0.0.2 from  outgoing for exampele 10.0.0.2 > some_client_ip , the client receive traffic from 10.0.0.2 which is not exist! and therefore connection fails!

Comment: I think you might need to explain [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/717104/edit) what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @roaima I think it's real clear! DNAT stop working if use -to-destination to one of interface IPs!

Comment: @Alireza Can you ping 1.2.3.5 from outside?

Comment: "_I think it's real clear!_" - you're not the one trying to answer the question. It's not clear to me, and I see at least two others who have indicated it's not clear to them either

Comment: The question is quite unclear to me, but do you really need DNAT? It seems to me that SNAT is what you need…